# Converting a Telerik ASP.NET application to MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I've done a little bit of poking around with this, and I am hoping it is not as bad as I think. I have an ASP.NET project using Telerik Control for ASP.NET AJAX integrated into an MVC solution. The .NET project runs fine, but is a circular block in a square hole. The interactions between my Telerik controls are complex.

Is it possible (at this current time) to recreate identical functionality using Telerik's MVC controls? For instance, I am looking to dynamically add nested controls to a RadSplitter. This was all done server-side before, and I am noting that the client-side functionality of RadSplitter for MVC is lacking.

I am not familiar with MVC aside from conceptually what it is. Is what I'm suggesting completely heinous? Do I need to wait longer for the controls to become more fleshed out? Or is it possible to pass off all this dynamic work to the server still in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to update the content of one of the panels you can do it using the client side API (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/splitter/clientsideapi)

> splitter.ajaxRequest(pane [, URL]) - refreshes the content of a pane with specified content URL (load-on-demand). If URL is specified, data is fetched from where it points to.

On a much broader note if you are hoping to easily convert your existing webforms solution to a MVC application then I have to say it isn't as easy as you would hope. As you know MVC as a completely different animal and the two technologies don't convert very easily. We are 6 months into our conversion and there have been some painful moments but overall it is absolutely worth it. The control you have over a MVC application is amazing and the speed and performance increases you can get if done correctly easily justify the time and cost.

Comment: I used the Telerik controls to create a Web Dashboard. The basic setup consits of an arbitrary amount of panes nested onto splitters w/ other controls ontop of them. I didn't see a means of dynamically adding a pane to an MVC splitter.

Answer (score 1):

The good news: What you are discussing is completely possible with teleriks mvc controls.

The bad news: You will need to gain a broader understanding of MVC. Most specifically the fact that there are no user controls. You can achieve the same behavior with partial views but the mechanisms to make this happen are a little different in ASP.NET MVC.

With that said if you have the option I would absolutely recommend you move to MVC its an AMAZING platform for creating web apps.**

```
**disclaimer: This is my opinion. Please refrain from demanding that I provide examples on why I enjoy working with MVC.
```